# Integrate ${\sin(x)\cos(x)}$ by parts, by letting ${u=\cos(x),dv=\sin(x)dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation-by-parts

I was able to integrate by parts using $u=\sin(x)$ but I'm trying to do it the other way.

With $\int \sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) dx$

$u = \cos\left(x\right)$

$dv = \sin\left(x\right) dx$

$v = -\cos\left(x\right)$

Then,
$I = uv - \int v \ du = -\cos\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right) + \int \cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right) \ dx$

but then I get $I = -\cos^2\left(x\right) + I \, $ and those $I$'s would cancel out and I would get zero? Assuredly, I'm missing a negative sign somewhere

Comment: Why do you want to integrate by parts? Your integral is really simple, for it is of the type $\int f(x) f^\prime (x)\ \text{d} x = \frac{1}{2}\ f^2(x) + C$ with $f(x) = \sin x$.

Comment: @Pacciu nevermind I misread what OP wrote. OP meant they did IBP via ${u=\sin(x), dv=\cos(x)dx}$, I thought they did substitution with ${u=\sin(x)}$. I'll edit my answer to explain that substitution is easier

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yep. And it is not a proper substitution… Maybe it’s one of the most basic rule of integration, coming from the chain rule for differentiation.

Comment: @Pacciu it is a proper substitution, integration by substitution says ${\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(x))\phi'(x)dx=\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(u)du}$. In this case, ${f(x)=x,\phi(x)=\sin(x)}$

Comment: A third way is to note that $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac12 \sin(2x)$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I meant that the rule $\int f^n(x) f^\prime (x) \text{d} x = \frac{1}{n+1} f^{n+1}(x)+C$ is really too immediate to invoke “integration by substitution theorem” to prove it. ;-)

Comment: @Pacciu Indeed, by the chain rule you can show ${\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}f^{n+1}(x)\right)=f^n(x)f'(x)}$ (assuming $f$ is differentiable), and indeed this proves the fact. But I kinda think using substitution is a more general and methodical approach which I'd argue would help in a lot more situations than in just this "special case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed missing a minus sign. ${\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x))=-\sin(x)}$. So the ${-\int vdu}$ part actually is

$${-\int (-\cos(x))(-\sin(x))dx=-\int\sin(x)\cos(x)=-I}$$

So

$${I = \cos^2(x) - I}$$

Which implies that

$${I = \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2}}$$

(obviously add the +c at the end). As required

**Edit**: This is a working solution (and nothing wrong with it). However, it's worth noting that it's also doable just by standard substitution. Notice that it is of the form

$${\int f(x)f'(x)dx}$$

where ${f(x) = \sin(x)}$. Letting ${u=\sin(x)}$ you get that ${du = \cos(x)dx\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{\cos(x)}}$, hence

$${\Rightarrow \int u\cos(x)\frac{du}{\cos(x)}=\int udu=\frac{1}{2}u^2 + c}$$

but we know ${u=\sin(x)}$ so

$${\int \sin(x)\cos(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x) + c}$$

So both solutions give the same answer, but indeed substitution is easier :)

**Edit Edit**: @MarkViola gave yet another way to integrate this by using the identity ${\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)}$. Notice that means your function, ${\sin(x)\cos(x)}$ is nothing but ${\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}}$, and hence

$${\int \sin(x)\cos(x)dx = \int \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}dx=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(2x)+c}$$

Comment: thanks :D

I knew the other one was easier, or at least more likely to be thought of first, but I did want to try out different methods to compare answers. Either way, it's good to see it laid out like this too :)

Comment: @Sat no problem! I did think that might be the case (that you wanted to try different methods out to compare), but just in case thought I'd add the little bit about substitution too. Glad it helped!

Comment: And yet a third way is to use the identity $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac12 \sin(2x)$.

Comment: @MarkViola Indeed! If OP is interested in extra methods for comparison sake, he might be interested in this too

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it is use a double angle identity.
$$I=\int \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\frac{-\cos(2x)}{4}+C$$
Integration by parts also works though.
$$I=\int \sin(x)\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$u=\cos(x), \mathrm{d}u=-\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}v=\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x, v=-\cos(x)$$
$$I=-\cos(x)\cos(x)-\int -\cos(x)(-\sin(x))\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=-\cos^2(x)-I$$
$$I=\frac{-\cos^2(x)}{2}+C.$$

Comment: Per my comment ...